# Package vegan add labels

Tags: r

I have two dataframes X and Y I am trying to plot them on a canonical corelation analysis (cca) plot with the vegan package. My problem is that when I perform the cca() I only get the vector's name from dataframe Y -  X1, X2... but not the data points from dataset X (that I have called p1, p2..). Since I don't have much points I would like to plot them but I cannot find how ..

```
library('CCA')
library('fastDummies')
library('vegan')
    
df <- read.csv("main.csv", encoding = "UTF-8", sep=";")

X <- df["Sign"]
Y <- df['Discip']

X <- dummy_cols(X, remove_selected_columns = TRUE)
Y <- dummy_cols(Y, remove_selected_columns = TRUE)

names(X) <- gsub(".*\\_", "", names(X))
names(Y) <- gsub(".*\\_", "", names(Y))

cc_results <- cca(X, Y)
plot(cc_results, xlim=c(-50, 75), ylim=c(-50, 50))
```

[image]
Data

```
> dput(head(X))
structure(list(Balance = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Belier = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Cancer = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Capricorne = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Gemeaux = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Lion = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Poissons = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Sagittaire = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Scorpion = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Taureau = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Verseau = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Vierge = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(head(Y))
structure(list(Chirurgie = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Imagerie = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Laboratoire = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    `Medecine generaliste` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Medecine specialiste` = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: We don't have access to `main.csv`. Can you provide a fully reproducible example?

Comment: I have the csv file but it is a 23,648 lines is it possible to add it ?

Comment: Can your precise plotting question be addressed with a smaller data set, possibly a fraction of your data set (in which case you could copy the output of `dput(head(df))` into the question)?

Comment: You want to show the variables (Balance, belier, ...) on the plot instead of X1, X2, ..?

Comment: I would like to plot everything on the plot: Chirurgie, imagerie... and balance, cancer ..

Comment: Some of variables in your X and Y are uniform with all having either 0 or 1.  So I  randomly replace with both 1 and 0 just as example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the `X` and `Y` making each variable taking both 1 and 0 values.
After `cca()` we could make first an `empty plot`, then adding `X` variables and `Y` arrows using `text()` and finally the data points using `points()` as follows:

```
library(vegan)
cc_results<-cca(X,Y)

# make empty plot (cca1 vs. cca2)
plot(cc_results
     ,type = "n"
     ,scaling=0
     ,xlim=c(-2.5,4.5) # adjust the limits
     ,ylim=c(-2,2) # adjust the limits
)

# plot X variables
text(cc_results, display="species", col="#0868ac", cex=.65, font=2)
# plot Y arrows
text(cc_results, display="bp", col="black", cex=.7, font=2) 
# plot the data points
points(cc_results, display="sites", pch=21, cex=.8, choices = c(1,2))
```

Example Dataset of X and Y

```
X<-structure(list(Balance = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Belier = c(0L,0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Cancer = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L),
  Capricorne = c(1L,0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Gemeaux = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Lion = c(0L,0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
  Poissons = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Sagittaire = c(1L,0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Scorpion = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L),
  Taureau = c(0L,1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Verseau = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Vierge = c(1L,0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), 
  row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Y<-structure(list(Chirurgie = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Imagerie = c(1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Laboratoire = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
        `Medecine generaliste` = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), `Medecine specialiste` = c(1L, 
        1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and finally the resulting plot
[image]

Comment: Do you have any idea of why "Laboratoire" does not appear on the plot ?

Comment: Because its values is identical with imagerie so I changed the values to be different from that variable. See my updates and Y example dataset

Comment: Alright I understand. It's weird because on the whole dataset I have medecine specialite who disapeared  even though the vector is not similar to the other ones.

Comment: May it is more important on other CCa scores or highly correlated. Or play with x,y limits adjustment.